# Serving a static file for a certain user agent

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl        on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example;
    index index.html;


    location / {
            if ( $http_user_agent = "Dinosaur" ) {
                rewrite https://example.com/ https://example.com/example.gif;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

In a request to the root of https://example.com, I want the index.html to be served. However, if the request is made with a special user agent, then I want it to serve the example.gif file directly (not 301 or 302 redirecting to the https://example.com/example.gif URL).

How can I do this? The rewrite doesn't appear to be working. The `try_files` directive doesn't work in an `if` context, which may or may not be necessary to check for the user agent condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct location statement for the root of `https://example.com` is `location = /`. The `location /` statement matches **any** URI that is not handled by some other location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Your `rewrite` statement is completely wrong. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Testing the value of the `$http_user_agent` is accomplished with an `if` block. You may want to use `~` instead of `=`, if the value *contains* "Dinosaur" rather than being an exact match. Also, statements within the `if` block should be limited to `rewrite...last` and `return`. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for details.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location = / {
    if ( $http_user_agent ~ "Dinosaur" ) {
        rewrite ^ /example.gif last;
    }
}
```

If the `if` block is not taken, the default action is to process the `index` statement and serve the `index.html` file.